# Pictures are streaky on Nikon D70

Tags: nikon-d70

So after a very long hibernation I dug up my D70. Upgraded the firmware to v.2 and took a picture. And this is the result (not on display but the real picture). Adn continued taking pictures with the same result. Is my D70 good for then camera graveyard? Anybody else had this problem and any solution available?

[image]

Comment: I almost never update a firmware. If it is not broken, do not fix it :o(

Comment: Where the photos like this before the updating? What was the reason for the update?

Comment: Same result before firmware update.

Answer (score 2):

The  fingers on the flat ribbon cable connector on the bottom of the camera, from the card socket to the main circuit board, probably needs to be cleaned. It's a common point of failure for the d70

Easy to do, download service manual from one of the different sites that has it